# Train custom trained Yolov8 model again with new samples

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I've trained a YOLOv8 model for object detection with one classes on a custom dataset.
Now I want to train it to detect more classes by increasing my dataset.

Instead of training the model from the start can I further train it specifically on the new dataset?